# How to load chinook database in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to load chinook database in SQLite but I have no idea how can I do that.
First, I used this command but it just made a file without anything in it:

```
sqlite3 chinook.db
```

I also downloaded [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=chinookdatabase) archive that contains chinook database but I couldn't find chinook.db file to open it with this command:

```
.open chinook.db
```

Answer (score 1):

We should script the database before using it. [Here](http://johnatten.com/2014/12/07/installing-and-using-sqlite-on-windows/) is the link that discussed the whole procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of the chinook database then just use the restore database feature.

```
cd /home/sqlite
mv sample.db sample.db.old
sqlite3 sample.db < sample.bak
```

For more information go to http://www.ibiblio.org/elemental/howto/sqlite-backup.html

Comment: there is no .db file in the chinook database that I downloaded

Comment: Try using the file path. This is an Example .open c:/sqlite/sample/SchoolDB.db